# Always return data from service

Tags: angularjs

I have a series of services that either fetch data from an API server, or return data if it exists in local storage.

```
.factory('LogEntryResource', function(config, $resource) {
  return $resource(config.apiUrl + 'logentries/:id/');
})

.factory('LogEntry', function(localStorageService, LogEntryResource) {
  var localLogEntries = localStorageService.get("logEntries");

  return {
    all: function() {
      if(localLogEntries){
        return localStorageService.get("logEntries");
      } else {
        return LogEntry.query(function(data){
          localStorageService.set("logEntries", data);
          return data;
        });
      }
    },
    get: function(logEntryId){
      ...
    },
    delete: function(logEntryId){
      ...
    },
    update: function(logEntryId){
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is that in the app controllers sometimes a promise is returned, and sometimes the data is returned, so I need to handle the return value of `LogEntry.all()` to either wait for the promise to resolve or to use the data.

I'm not really sure how to go about it because I can either use a `.then()` which works for the promise, but is undefined if it has data, or vice-versa. I know I'm doing something wrong and looking for advice how to handle this situation of dealing with either data or a promise being returned.

```
.controller('LogEntryCtrl', function($scope, LogEntry) {
  // var data = LogEntry.all();
  // var promise = LogEntry.all();

  $scope.logEntry = ???
}
```

I'm hoping there's a nice reusable solution instead of having to do a check to see what it is every time I use this code in my controllers/routes

```
 // trying to avoid doing this
 var logEntry = LogEntry.all();

 if(logEntry.isPromise){
   // do promise stuff here
 } else if(logEntry.isData {
   // do data stuff here
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried .then(function (data){});  to resolve the promise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be always return a promise. You can use `$q.resolve()` to create a shortcut for a resolved promise

```
.factory('LogEntry', function(localStorageService, LogEntry, $q) {
  var localLogEntries = localStorageService.get("logEntries");

  return {
    all: function() {
      if(localLogEntries){
        return $q.resolve(localLogEntries);
      } else {
        return LogEntry.query(function(data){
          localStorageService.set("logEntries", data);
          // update variable also
          localLogEntries = data;
          return localLogEntries ;
        });
      }
    },
```

In controller you always use `then()` this way

```
LogEntry.all().then(function(data){
   $scope.data = data;
});
```

Comment: agree with @charlietfl . $q is a great solution to your problem